# Merging Two Arrays with Same Index in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, merge

I want to Merge Two Array With Same Index,
This is my JSON

```
"tier_info": [
    {
        "tier_id": "1",
        "tier_name": "tier-1",
        "price": "3.9",
        "ios_id": "tier-1",
        "android_id": "tier-1"
    },
    {
        "tier_id": "2",
        "tier_name": "tier-2",
        "price": "4.9",
        "ios_id": "tier-2",
        "android_id": "tier-2"
    },
    {
        "tier_id": "3",
        "tier_name": "tier-3",
        "price": "5.9",
        "ios_id": "tier-3",
        "android_id": "tier-3"
    },
    {
        "tier_id": "4",
        "tier_name": "free",
        "price": "0",
        "ios_id": "free",
        "android_id": "free"
    }
]
```

I'm using custom picker, Now I want "tier_name" with "price" in same array index [e.g. "tier_1 : 3.9"].
  Code of merging two Array:

```
    NSMutableArray *tierTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    tierTitles = [tierArray valueForKey:@"tier_name"];
    NSMutableArray *tierPrice = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    tierPrice = [tierArray valueForKey:@"price"];

    NSMutableArray *combined = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < tierArray.count; i++) {
        [combined addObject: @{tierTitles[i]:tierPrice[i]}];
    }
```

and i got this

```
(
    {
    "tier-1" = "3.9";
},
    {
    "tier-2" = "4.9";
},
    {
    "tier-3" = "5.9";
},
    {
    free = 0;
}
)
```

i want it like :

```
  (
    "tier-1" = "3.9";
    "tier-2" = "4.9";
    "tier-3" = "5.9";
    free = 0;
  )
```

what am i doing wrong here..any correct way to do this?

Comment: What is your answer expected type ? It looks like an Array of Dictionary, so the previous result is ok to me

Comment: i'm getting combined array in NSMutable Array

Comment: You want `{"tier-1" = "3.9"; "tier-2" = "4.9"; "tier-3" = "5.9"; free = 0;}` (aka one dictionary) not  `("tier-1" = "3.9"; "tier-2" = "4.9"; "tier-3" = "5.9"; free = 0;)` no? Because yours is something strange, the `()` in print in Objective-C are for a NSArray, and `{}` for a NSDictionary, and I don't know what's `"tier-1" = "3.9";` in a NSArray.

Comment: i want in NSMutableArray not in NSDictionary
but i got Array of Dictionary...

Comment: only way to get an array is create a string like "tier-1 = 3.9" that is not appropriate.

Comment: @KetanOdedra Your target result is still unclear. Could you construct it yourself with hardcoded/dummy values? Only the result, and then print it? You'll see that your question is not clear then and maybe the result isn't the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're asking is you need an NSDictionary that contains both name and price as key-value.You need to enumerate each object and add it to an array if the value exist :-

```
NSMutableArray *results=[NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *tier in tierArray]) {
    if ([tier[@"tier_name"] length] && [tier[@"price"] length]) {
        [results addObject:@{tier[@"tier_name"]:tier[@"price"]:}];
    }
}
```

Or create a Mutable Dictionary Like this:-

```
NSMutableDictionary *results=[NSMutableDictionary new];
for (NSDictionary *tier in tierArray) {
    if ([tier[@"tier_name"] length] && [tier[@"price"] length]) {
        [results setValue:tier[@"price" forKey:tier[@"tier_name"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: create a Mutable Dictionary is right but same way can i create single Array ?

Comment: you can create a array but which data type will you add in your array to add both 
your tier and price? only possible way to do it do add a dictionary with key value pari @KetanOdedra another alternative would be using a string if you want to add it to an array but i don't think it'll be useful and it'll not make any sense.

Comment: no problem at all, let me remove the suggestion : ) @KetanOdedra

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add dictionary to your combined array like as below

```
 [tierTitles enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSMutableDictionary*combinedDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [combinedDict setValue:[tierPrice objectAtIndex:idx] forKey:obj];
    [combined addObject: combinedDict];
}];
```

Comment: its return same which is in my question.